# Activity is opening multiple times using broadcast receiver

Tags: java, android, android-activity, broadcast, android-broadcastreceiver

I am developing android app which work as battery indicator, open activity when battery low or full.

It works fine when i call finish() in Main activity from onCreate event after start of service.

but when i comment finish method it open activity multiple times, which i open from BroadCast receiver.

**Here is MainActivity Code:**

```
public class Main extends Activity {
private MyService service;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.main);

if (service == null) {

    Intent i = new Intent(this, MyService.class);
    startService(i);
}

finish();
}}
```

Here is my service code:
I think i am doing something wrong when i start Activity.
At line

```
getApplication().startActivity(intent);
```

**Complete Service Code is:**

```
public class MyService extends Service{

@Override
public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return null;
}

@Override
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
    Log.d("MyService", "onStartCommand");
    // do not receive all available system information (it is a filter!)
    final IntentFilter battChangeFilter = new IntentFilter(
            Intent.ACTION_BATTERY_CHANGED);
    // register our receiver
    this.registerReceiver(this.batteryChangeReceiver, battChangeFilter);
    return super.onStartCommand(intent, flags, startId);
}
private final BroadcastReceiver batteryChangeReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {

    @Override
    public void onReceive(final Context context, final Intent intent) {
        checkBatteryLevel(intent);
    }
};

private void checkBatteryLevel(Intent batteryChangeIntent) {
    // some calculations
    final int currLevel = batteryChangeIntent.getIntExtra(
            BatteryManager.EXTRA_LEVEL, -1);
    final int maxLevel = batteryChangeIntent.getIntExtra(
            BatteryManager.EXTRA_SCALE, -1);
    final int percentage = (int) Math.round((currLevel * 100.0) / maxLevel);

    if(percentage==100)
    {
        Intent intent = new Intent(getBaseContext(), Last.class);
        intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
        getApplication().startActivity(intent);

    }
    if(percentage==15)
    {
        Intent intent = new Intent(getBaseContext(), Last.class);
        intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
        getApplication().startActivity(intent);

    }
    }}
```

> And this is my last "Last.cs" activity which is opening multiple time.
>   but it works fine when i call finish() into Main Activity.

```
public class Last extends Activity {
Button btnCancel;
Uri notification;
Ringtone r;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.activity_last);

notification = RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_RINGTONE);
r = RingtoneManager.getRingtone(getApplicationContext(), notification);
r.play();


 btnCancel = (Button) findViewById(R.id.stopsound);

 btnCancel.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

    public void onClick(View v) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

         r.stop();
    }
});

}  }
```

Comment: Too much code. Post only necessary parts

Comment: You can implement broadcast receiver in your activity, why using service to implement broadcast

Comment: @Clairvoyant if i close activity or application then how can i receive broadcast ??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Make your Last activity launchMode as **singleTask** in Manifest

```
 <activity
      android:name=".Last"
      android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize"
      android:launchMode="singleTask"
      >
  </activity>
```

Comment: If this answer help you to avoid creating multiple activity.Please accept it as answer it may be useful for others who are facing the same problem.

Comment: but why it works when i call finish on main activity ??

Comment: is there any problem at getApplication().startActivity(intent); in service code ??

Comment: another question.. it will relaunch activity or not ?? when i want ??

Comment: Just spend sometime to learn about the launchMode in http://developer.android.com/guide/components/tasks-and-back-stack.html Still if you are not able to understand then ask me please.